# Issues with nested views using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The issue I'm having is that for some reason when navigating to the users home aside from it not loading and causing my browser to freeze when I inspect the console. (I take out the abstract: true from app.user) in the console it shows  the 's of my of app.user.base nested inside each other with the top  being the mainview and the footer getting loading inside of it. What Am i doing wrong?

```
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('app.user', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/user',
        templateURL: 'app/user/user.html'
    })
    .state('app.user.base, {
        url: '',
        views: {
            mainView: {
                template: '<ui-view/>'
            }
            footer: {
                templateUrl: 'app/user/views/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.user.base.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateURL: 'app/user/views/home.html',
        controller: 'uHomeCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.user.base.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateURL: 'app/user/views/profile.html',
        controller: 'uProfileCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.main, {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        templateURL: 'app/main/main.html'
    })
   .state('app.main.home, {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
        landing: {
           templateUrl: 'app/main/views/landing.html',
           controller: 'landingCtrl'
         },
        about: {
           templateUrl: 'app/main/views/about.html',
           controller: 'aboutCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Is your code copy and pasted? because you are missing a few `'`s

Comment: Apart from missing ' and , in your above code, would you mind showing what you have wrote in those html's ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you can have it the same url's '/home' in few places, please read this [article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) about nested states I may help to fix you issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to remove url property from all the states you have that are not navigable. Do that first, then see what new errors you get. URLs are not at all required to be able to navigate to a state.